# How to use Oracle Managed DataAcess provider to access a local Oracle XE 11.2 instance?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, ado.net, connection-string

I downloaded and installed Oracle XE 11.2 on my developer machine. I managed to access it with SQL Plus using the SYSTEM username and the given password.

Now for testing purposes I need to access this database from our .NET application, where we're using Oracle Managed DataAccess provider (latest version).

I've found very little documentation on the internet, basically only one article which suggested using a connection string with this form:

```
data source=XE;user id=...;password=...
```

So I tried using it like this:

```
data source=XE;user id=SYSTEM;password=myPassword
```

but the connection wasn't succesful, and I have no clue what I should do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my question because in the meantime I've figured out a working connection string, here it is:

```
 <add 
name="Default" 
connectionString="Data Source=(SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE))));User ID=system;Password=XXXX;" 
providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"/>
```